Cannot drop database from broken Availability Group, stuck "Reverting / In Recovery"
A colleague of mine new to Availability Groups and SQL Administration has been working on an issue in our Test environment - SQL Server 2022, 16.0.4165.4.
He has cancelled the creation of an Availability Group before it finished processing, and deleted the database from the Availability Group before it could finish rolling back changes.
We now have a database that is not part of an Availability Group and is stuck Reverting / In Recovery.
This is preventing users from being able to use the Test system for UAT.
Things checked and tested:

I cannot drop the database as it is in a process unable for checks.
I cannot take the DB offline because it is in use.
I cannot replace the DB with a backup as it is in use.
I cannot detach the DB as it is in use.
Restarting the SQL Instance and/or server does not resolve anything.
There are no active sessions for this database so cannot kill any
I cannot set the database as single user
I cannot restore the database with recovery

I basically cannot fix this problem and am wondering if anyone else has any other solutions or suggestions here - or do we actually need to wait for this "Reverting" process to finish?
Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated.

What happens if you physically delete the database files from the system (after shutting down the instance)?


He has cancelled the creation of an Availability Group before it finished processing, and deleted the database from the Availability Group before it could finish rolling back changes.
We now have a database that is not part of an Availability Group and is stuck Reverting / In Recovery.

There's more to this story for sure, but that isn't the main question so I'll move along.

I basically cannot fix this problem and am wondering if anyone else has any other solutions or suggestions here - or do we actually need to wait for this "Reverting" process to finish?

Since the AG is supposedly gone (though we have no data verifying this or how it was configured) it shouldn't stay in the reverting phase and would typically move to be suspect (WSFC based, though WSFC/SQL issues could cause metadata staleness) however if it's not WSFC based it will just sit there and keep trying to connect to a primary that no longer exists.
ex: Synchronization of a secondary database, 'Database_Name_Here', was interrupted, leaving the database in an inconsistent state. The database will be marked SUSPECT. To return the database to a consistent state, restore it from a clean database backup followed by all subsequent log backups.
If it's still sitting in reverting and it is cluster type NONE then you can execute ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [name] OFFLINE as the availability group still exists on that replica (which means it's not gone as stated in the OP). This will then move the database into a recovery pending state, which you can then drop. Don't forget to drop the AG on the local replica after removing the database. If it's in a WSFC then there is something wrong with the metadata in the instance or the metadata in the WSFC and doing anything outside of restarting the instance to clear out the metadata in SQL Server could end up causing more damage.
